# Set red color to NaN values with matplotlibs with subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot four arrays arranged in subplots using Python and matplotlib.
I prefer grey scale colormap.
How to plot the NaN values that can be present in each array in red?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import gdal

raster1 = gdal.Open("/path/file1.tif")   
array1 = np.array(raster1.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()) 
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(array1, 
           vmin=0, vmax=1, 
           cmap=cm.get_cmap("Greys_r"))

raster2 = gdal.Open("/path/file2.tif")   
array1 = np.array(raster2.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()) 
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(array2, 
           vmin=0, vmax=1, 
           cmap=cm.get_cmap("Greys_r"))

raster3 = gdal.Open("/path/file3.tif")   
array3 = np.array(raster3.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()) 
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.imshow(array3, 
           vmin=0, vmax=1, 
           cmap=cm.get_cmap("Greys_r"))

raster4 = gdal.Open("/path/file4.tif")   
array4 = np.array(raster4.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()) 
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.imshow(array4, 
           vmin=0, vmax=1, 
           cmap=cm.get_cmap("Greys_r"))
```

Comment: Where is the geospatial component of your question ?

Comment: Hi Gene, I tried to add the geospatial info you asked me

Answer (score 0):

Look this code:

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Open raster
raster = gdal.Open(inputpath_raster)

# Open like band
band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)

# Read numpy array
array = band.ReadAsArray()

# Creat a mask
masked_array = np.ma.array (array, mask=np.isnan(array))

# Make a copy
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap("Greys_r").copy()

# Choose the color
cmap.set_bad('red',1.)

# Plot
plt.imshow(masked_array, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The same process for each raster